# java.lang.ClassNotFound: Didn't find class “android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication” on path: DexPathList

Tags: android, react-native, android-multidex

I`m trying to enable multidex on my app of react-native but I get a error when the app is launched.

I already did the steps in the official doc of android: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex

My build.gradel (android/app/build.gradel)

```
 defaultConfig {
        ....
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    ...

    dependencies {
      implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

      implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])

      implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules

      implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0"

       ...
    }
```

And my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application
  android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"

  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
  android:allowBackup="false"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

  ...

</application>
```

I don't understand what the problem is, why the error keeps happening when I start de app.

I`m using react-native V0.62.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> java.lang.ClassNotFound: Didn't find class
>   “android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication” on path: DexPathList

**Don't**

```
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
```

And

```
<application
  android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
```

**`AndroidX`** replaces the original support library APIs with packages in the androidx namespace. So try with

```
<application
  android:name="androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
```

**FYI**

You should call

```
 implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
```

Then **`Clean-Rebuild-Run`**.

Comment: Hello, I just tried your correction, I am having a change in the error message. ** unable to start activity ComponentInfo: ... MainActivity; androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication cannot be cast to com.facebook.react.ReactAplication. **    IMG: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HX8DJyIRiM9fSgnhH2eOZB4H3wJ6Bgc5/view

Comment: @DADM sorry, edited my answer. use `implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'`. Hope this will works

Comment: change the <application
  android: name = "androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication"  To                      <application
  android: name = "". MainApplication "

and finally it worked, obviously many thanks @IntelliJ for the correction in:                        implementation 'androidx.multidex: multidex: 2.0.1'